# WebGL get a string value from features

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to get an string value from the features? Now is a nummeric value ...
The use of a string value would be for example an colorstring ...

["get", "attributeName"] fetches a numeric attribute value for each feature

Answer (score 0):

Only numeric values can be used in numeric operations but ["get", "attributeName"] should return a string for string values

For example in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html

if you edit

```
  "symbol": {
    "symbolType": "circle",
    "size": [
      "interpolate",
      [
        "linear"
      ],
      [
        "get",
        "population"
      ],
      40000,
      8,
      2000000,
      28
    ],
```

to

```
  "symbol": {
    "symbolType": "circle",
    "size": [
      "match",
      [
        "get",
        "country"
      ],
      "br",
      8,
      28
    ],
```

the circles for all cities in Brazil will be size 8, and elsewhere size 28.

Comment: But if I would like to set the color of a feature from a colorstring ? I can use a numeric value for the color but something like "rgba(....)"